# How can I properly index my data using Elasticsearch es.index and helpers.bulk in Python and how can I set up mapping for my data?

Tags: javascript, python, reactjs, elasticsearch, search-engine

I'm trying to build my website functionality with elastic search. As I'm using Elasticsearch es.index to ingest data as well as helpers.bulk, I'm unable to properly index my data and don't understand mappings in order to change it as I refer to the Elasticsearch Data Index API doc when seeing if the data gets ingested. It does get ingested but in an improper format which I'm unable to understand. I configured and connected to Elasticsearch in loadJSONMovies inside my scrape.py file and followed this guide  [https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-helpers-to-bulk-load-data-into-an-elasticsearch-index#two+key+benefit[…]+bulk+api%5C%27s](https://kb.objectrocket.com/elasticsearch/how-to-use-python-helpers-to-bulk-load-data-into-an-elasticsearch-index#two+key+benefit%5B%E2%80%A6%5D+bulk+api%5C%27s). I understand I don't have to use helpers/bulk for this method and would like proper direction as to passing the json object instead a string to one api call. I only have about 600 queries inside my json file and the end goal I want to achieve is to be able to make API calls with these queries by genre and airline. https://elasticstack.slack.com/files/U02V89YPGV9/F059LF7U1ME/data.json

This is the error I get when I attempt to ingest the data.json file manually and I want to be able to do this process by ingesting the dictionary as a string to JSON, then to Elasticsearch using es.index or helpers.bulk in Python and want directions as how to set up mappings for my data                                                                                                                                                                                    File structure cannot be determined
If you know something about this data, such as the file format or timestamp format, adding initial overrides may help us to infer the rest of the structure.
[illegal_argument_exception Root causes: illegal_argument_exception: Input contained too few lines [1] to obtain a meaningful sample]: Input contained too few lines [1] to obtain a meaningful sampleExplanation so far:
[Using character encoding [UTF-8], which matched the input with [15%] confidence - first [8kB] of input was pure ASCII].

Here is my Python Script for the given issue.

def loadJSONMovies():

```
# Setting up ElasticSearch Configuration to API
config = configparser.ConfigParser()
config.read('example.ini')
# build_doc = {}
# build_doc["_index"] = "am-movies"
# build_doc["_id"] = 12345
# build_doc["doc_type"]
# build_doc["_source"] = str(air_movie_data)

es = Elasticsearch(cloud_id=config['ELASTIC']['cloud_id'], basic_auth=(config['ELASTIC']['user'], config['ELASTIC']['password']))

actions = [{"_id" : uuid.uuid4(), "doc_type" : "movies", "doc": air_movie_data}
for doc in range(100)]

with open("data.json", "w") as outfile:
    outfile.write(str(air_movie_data))

def script_path():
    path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
    if os.name == 'posix': # posix is for macOS or Linux
        path = path + "/"
    else:
        path = path + chr(92) # backslash is for Windows
    return path

def get_data_from_file(file_name):
    if "/" in file_name or chr(92) in file_name:
        file = open(file_name, encoding="utf8", errors='ignore')
    else:
    # use the script_path() function to get path if none is passed
        file = open(script_path() + str(file_name), encoding="utf8", errors='ignore')
    data = [line.strip() for line in file]
    file.close()
    return data

def bulk_json_data(json_file, _index, doc_type):
    json_list = get_data_from_file(json_file)
    for doc in json_list:
        # use a `yield` generator so that the data
        # isn't loaded into memory
        if "{Title" not in doc:
            yield {
                "_index": _index,
                "_id": uuid.uuid4(),
                "_source": doc
            }
    return

try:
# make the bulk call, and get a response
    response = helpers.bulk(es, bulk_json_data("data.json", "am-movies", "movies"))

#response = helpers.bulk(elastic, actions, index='employees', doc_type='people')
    print ("\nRESPONSE:", response)
except Exception as e:
    print("\nERROR:", e)

# try:
# # create JSON string of doc _source data
#     json_source = json.dumps(build_doc["source"])

# # get the dict object's _id
#     json_id = build_doc["id"]
#     build_doc["source"] = json_source
# # make an API call to the Elasticsearch cluster
#     response = es.index(
#         #Index name in Kibana
#         index = 'search-am',
#         document = json_source
#     )
#     print
#     # print a pretty response to the index() method call response
#     print ("\nclient.index response:", json.dumps(response, indent=4))
# except Exception as error:
#     print ("Error type:", type(error))
#     print ("client.index() ERROR:", error)
# print(es.info)

# print ("\nbuild_doc items:", build_doc.items())

# es.index(index="my-index-000001", document=air_movie_data.values())
# helpers.bulk(es, json_str)

# all_docs = {}
# all_docs["size"] = 9999
# all_docs["query"] = {"match_all" : {}}
# print ("\nall_docs:", all_docs)
# print ("all_docs TYPE:", type(all_docs))


# try:
#     # pass the JSON string in an API call to the Elasticsearch cluster
#     response = es.search(
#     index = "some_index",
#     body = all_docs
#     )

#     # print all of the documents in the Elasticsearch index
#     print ("all_docs query response:", response)

#     # use the dumps() method's 'indent' parameter to print a pretty response
#     print ("all_docs pretty:", json.dumps(response, indent=4))

# except Exception as error:
#     print ("Error type:", type(error))
#     print ("client.search() ValueError for JSON object:", error)

#Testing for proper JSON Format
```

I was expecting them to ingest automatically properly as the queries all have value data and yet I'm receiving this ERROR: 1 document(s) failed to index despite them being ingested in an improper format, but valid JSON Format.